# PyInstaller Missing Module Error with pyfiglet package

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I want to build a standalone executable VLI tool that will make use of pyfiglet package. When I ran `pyinstaller --onefile main.py` it resulted in some warnings in `build/warn-main.txt` file.
.

I have changed the main.spec generated, adding `"pyfiglet.fonts"` and some other missing modules, and then executed `pyinstaller --onefile main.spec`. After which only the pyfiglet.fonts was "solved".

Originally I was running the code in Windows 10 Pro, but as I didn't find a solution, I installed a clean VM with linux and python just for testing...

I'm running on a clean ubuntu 19.04 install with:
- python3 (3.7.3) installation from the default repositories
- no virtual env
- added 
- Installed pyinstaller (3.5) simple as `pip install pyinstaller`

With this very basic code the issues happens

```
import pyfiglet
print("Basic Work...")
ascii_banner = pyfiglet.figlet_format("Works...")
print(ascii_banner)
```

the missing modules are:

```
missing module named pyimod03_importers - imported by /home/masterlocal/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/rthooks/pyi_rth_pkgres.py (top-level)
missing module named _winreg - imported by platform (delayed, optional), /home/masterlocal/code/cliexe/main.py (top-level), pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed, conditional)
missing module named java - imported by platform (delayed), /home/masterlocal/code/cliexe/main.py (top-level)
missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform (delayed, optional), /home/masterlocal/code/cliexe/main.py (top-level), xml.sax._exceptions (conditional)
missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform (delayed, conditional, optional), /home/masterlocal/code/cliexe/main.py (top-level)
missing module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request (conditional)
missing module named org - imported by pickle (optional), /home/masterlocal/code/cliexe/main.py (top-level)
missing module named msvcrt - imported by subprocess (conditional), click._compat (conditional, optional), click._winconsole (top-level), getpass (optional), click._termui_impl (conditional), /home/masterlocal/code/cliexe/main.py (top-level)
missing module named _winapi - imported by encodings (delayed, conditional, optional), subprocess (conditional), /home/masterlocal/code/cliexe/main.py (top-level)
missing module named winreg - imported by platform (delayed, optional), mimetypes (optional), /home/masterlocal/code/cliexe/main.py (top-level), urllib.request (delayed, conditional, optional), pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed, conditional)
missing module named pkg_resources.extern.six - imported by pkg_resources.extern (top-level), pkg_resources (top-level), pkg_resources.py31compat (top-level), /home/masterlocal/code/cliexe/main.py (top-level)
missing module named 'pkg_resources.extern.six.moves' - imported by pkg_resources (top-level), /home/masterlocal/code/cliexe/main.py (top-level), pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.requirements (top-level)
missing module named pkg_resources.extern.appdirs - imported by pkg_resources.extern (top-level), pkg_resources (top-level), /home/masterlocal/code/cliexe/main.py (top-level)
missing module named pkg_resources.extern.packaging - imported by pkg_resources.extern (top-level), pkg_resources (top-level), /home/masterlocal/code/cliexe/main.py (top-level)
missing module named __main__ - imported by pkg_resources (delayed, optional), /home/masterlocal/code/cliexe/main.py (top-level)
missing module named 'pkg_resources.extern.pyparsing' - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.requirements (top-level), pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.markers (top-level)
missing module named 'ctypes.macholib' - imported by ctypes.util (conditional)
missing module named netbios - imported by uuid (delayed)
missing module named win32wnet - imported by uuid (delayed)
missing module named __builtin__ - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing (conditional)
missing module named ordereddict - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing (optional)
missing module named 'win32com.shell' - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (conditional, optional)
missing module named 'com.sun' - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named com - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed)
missing module named win32api - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named win32com - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed)
missing module named StringIO - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.six (conditional)
missing module named nt - imported by os (conditional, optional), ntpath (conditional, optional), shutil (conditional), /home/masterlocal/code/cliexe/main.py (top-level)
excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), /home/masterlocal/code/cliexe/main.py (top-level)
missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), /home/masterlocal/code/cliexe/main.py (top-level)
missing module named 'org.python' - imported by copy (optional), /home/masterlocal/code/cliexe/main.py (top-level), xml.sax (delayed, conditional)
missing module named colorama - imported by click._compat (conditional, optional)
```

I'm new in Python, so, not much experience on how to do it, but based on many posts I read, there isn't much details. I've checked the documentation on how to install and requeriments and everything (which isn't much) is as expected.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Look on hiddenimport parameter of pyinstaller. It force some modules to be included.

Comment: As I said, I did it for one package that worked "pyfiglet.fonts" but others like the first one in the missing list "pyimod03_importers" didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I good look the problem is in implementation of loading fonts in `pyfiglet`.

I suggest to replace it with custom:

```py
import pyfiglet
import pyfiglet.fonts
import pkg_resources
import os

class MyFigletFont(pyfiglet.FigletFont):
    @classmethod
    def preloadFont(cls, font):
        """
        Load font data if exist
        """
        base_path = os.path.dirname(pyfiglet.fonts.__file__)
        for extension in ('tlf', 'flf'):
            fn = '%s.%s' % (font, extension)
            """
               I chnage theese 3 lines.
               original use pkg_resources.resource_exists
            """  
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(base_path, fn)):
                with open(os.path.join(base_path, fn), 'rb') as f:
                    return f.read().decode('UTF-8', 'replace')
            else:
                for location in ("./", pyfiglet.SHARED_DIRECTORY):
                    full_name = os.path.join(location, fn)
                    if os.path.isfile(full_name):
                        with open(full_name, 'rb') as f:
                            return f.read().decode('UTF-8', 'replace')
        else:
            raise FontNotFound(font)

pyfiglet.FigletFont = MyFigletFont # here I change implementation of font loader 

print("Basic Work...")
ascii_banner = pyfiglet.figlet_format("Works...")
print(ascii_banner)
```

and spec file (remember to update paths)

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None
import os 
import pyfiglet.fonts

a = Analysis(['test3.py'],
             pathex=['/home/czaki/Pobrane/tmp/test_pyqt'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(pyfiglet.fonts.__file__), "*.f*"), os.path.join("pyfiglet", "fonts"))],
             hiddenimports=["pyfiglet.fonts"],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='test3',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='test3')
```

Answer (score 1):

PyInstaller won't recognize libraries with external dependencies like templates, DLLs, etc. So if you are freezing modules like this you need to feed them manually to your final executable.

`pyfiglet` needs its external `font` dependence, so you can add it by [`add-data`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/spec-files.html#adding-data-files) flag.
E.g:

```
pyinstaller -F --add-data "<python directory>/Lib/site-packages/pyfiglet/fonts;./pyfiglet/fonts" script.py
```

The above command would resolve to import `pyfiglet` on Windows. Also, I suggest you always use a `virtualenv` with PyInstaller as it creates a fresh Python environment.

Comment: thanks for the tip about always using virtualenv. I was using, but as I was getting some error and built a clean OS/Python install, I used without virtualenv